# Getting peak value of a column in table till this date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle table having columns {date, id, profit, max_profit}.

I have data in date and profit, and I want highest value of profit till date in max_profit, I am using query below

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE a SET a.MAX_PROFIT = (SELECT MAX(b.PROFIT) 
                                      FROM MY_TABLE b  WHERE b.DATE <= a.DATE 
                                                         AND a.id = b.id)
```

This is giving me correct result, but I have millions of rows for which query is taking considerable time, any faster way of doing it ?

Comment: Do you need to run this on all dates? You could possibly improve performance with a filter on where a.maxprofit is null. Obviously depends on how your data is getting updated. Else just check the last week (or x days, something along those lines)

Comment: There are some other methods.  http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_efficient_update_sql_dml_tips.htm . Use them if you know how to use..

Comment: probably, you may create a composite index like `CREATE INDEX idx_myt_idDate ON MY_TABLE(ID,myDATE) TABLESPACE myIndextbs`;

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MERGE` statement with an analytic function:

```
MERGE INTO my_table dst
USING (
  SELECT ROWID rid,
         MAX( profit ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY "DATE" ) AS max_profit
  FROM   my_table
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET max_profit = src.max_profit;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like "SELECT MAX(...)" you're going to scan all the records implicated in the 'WHERE" part of the query, so you want to make getting all those records as easy on the database as possible.

Do you have an index on the table that includes the id and date columns?

Depending on the behavior of this application, if you're doing a lot fewer updates/inserts (as opposed to doing a ton of reads during reporting or some other process), a possible performance enhancement might be to keep the value you're storing in the max_profit column up to date somewhere while you're changing the data. Have you considered a separate table that just stores the profit calculation for each possible date?